# initialize an object via enum classes

Tags: c#, oop

i am building a small app that act like a digital camera and i am trying to understand if this is a good oop way, after i build a camera object i am "giving" it a memory card class, the memory class get the type of card from enum class and the size form a enum class,

now i need to incorporate those two into an array that is the memory card.

```
    public enum MemoryCardType
{
    Sd,
    xd,
    MicroSd,

}
    public enum MemoryCardSize
{
    TwoGB = 2024,
    FourGB = 4048,
    EightGB = 8096

}
    public class MemoryCard
{

    public MemoryCard(MemoryCardType memoryCardType, MemoryCardSize memoryCardSize)
    {
        this.MemoryCardType = memoryCardType;
        this.MemoryCardSize = memoryCardSize;
    }

    public MemoryCardType MemoryCardType { get; set; }
    public MemoryCardSize MemoryCardSize { get; set; }
}
```

is this the best/right way?

Comment: Slight aside, your values are off: 2GB = 2048 MB, 4GB = 4096 MB, 8GB = 8192 MB

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your approach, but it really depends on how you plan to use the class.

What you should be wary of, however, is code that inspects an object (in this case, the type/size of the memory card) of your class to work out how to use the object. As far as possible, it should be up to the object to decide what to do with its state, not external/client code.

This may seem vague, but without more detail it's difficult to give any concrete advice.

---

However, is there a reason you've chosen to use the size in megabytes as the values for your enums? It's not at all obvious to someone using your code that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not use enums if the values really mean something pretty important. You cannot really ensure that the values are what you expect. Especially, if there are other developers working on the same project.

Here's what I would do:

```
abstract class MemoryCardSize
{
    public int MegaBytes { get; protected set; }
}

class TwoGB : MemoryCardSize { public TwoGB() { MegaBytes = 2024; } }
class FourGB : MemoryCardSize { public FourGB() { MegaBytes = 4048; } }
class EightGB : MemoryCardSize { public EightGB() { MegaBytes = 8096; } }
```

Comment: What benefit is there in using a class? Are you supposed to distrust the the arguments you're given?

Comment: And what if I do `class FakeTwoGB : TwoGB { public FakeTwoGB() { MegaBytes = 9000; } }`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the Factory design pattern :
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19335/Guide-to-Implement-the-Factory-Pattern-in-C.htm

Comment: Why? There is only one class.

Comment: ...with the caveat that the Factory pattern is probably the most overused pattern that there is. Make sure it really is appropriate before you go wading in.

Answer (score -1):

Example to factory:

```
public static class MemoryCardFactory
    {
        public static MemoryCard Sd2GB { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.xd, MemoryCardSize.TwoGB); } }
        public static MemoryCard Sd4GB { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.xd, MemoryCardSize.FourGB); } }
        public static MemoryCard Sd8B { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.xd, MemoryCardSize.EightGB); } }

        public static MemoryCard Xd2GB { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.xd, MemoryCardSize.TwoGB); } }
        public static MemoryCard Xd4GB { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.xd, MemoryCardSize.FourGB); } }
        public static MemoryCard Xd8GB { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.xd, MemoryCardSize.EightGB); } }

        public static MemoryCard MicroSd2GB { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.MicroSd, MemoryCardSize.TwoGB); } }
        public static MemoryCard MicroSd4GB { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.MicroSd, MemoryCardSize.FourGB); } }
        public static MemoryCard MicroSd8GB { get { return MemoryCard(MemoryCardType.MicroSd, MemoryCardSize.EightGB); } }
    }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
MemoryCard mc= MemoryCardFactory.MicroSd2GB;
```

Comment: ...so what's the advantage of this?

Comment: hmm... seems like a lot of code...not sure if its the best way. lets say i have 6 types and 12 sizes . it will be 72 lines :(

Comment: @darko Precisely; don't do this.

Comment: It's only for example.....and the advantage is that the developer that use this code in the future no need to know how to make the all class combinations